# OrientDB TTL for edges of a graph

Tags: orientdb, orientdb2.2

Is there a way to assign TTL to edges of a graph? TTL feature is included in [this](https://github.com/orientechnologies/orientdb/milestone/116?closed=1) milestone.

If there is not, what would be a workaround to remove edges after a period?

Comment: Hi, did you need to remove all the edges contained in a class? Do you want to remove them automatically or manually? Thx

Comment: I want to remove all the edges after a certain duration automatically.

Comment: Did you already took a look at this? https://orientdb.com/docs/2.2.x/Dynamic-Hooks.html

Comment: Have you tried in orientdb v3.0-m2?